# Unhide all .htaccess files on mac

Tags: macos, bash, find, xargs, htaccess

I am trying to unhide all the .htaccess files in my home folder. Below I've pasted what I'm using now, but it isn't working.

```
find ~/ -iname ".htaccess" | xargs chflags nohidden "{}"
```

Anyone knows why it keeps giving me errors that the file does not exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `hidden`/`nohidden` flags on a dotfile isn't going to make it appear. Finder always hides dotfiles, unless you set the `AppleShowAllFiles` property:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
```

That, however, will make *all* hidden files appear.

<sub>As for the errors you're getting, it's hard to tell. Not that it's going to make a difference because the files will still be hidden, but maybe try `find ~ -iname '.htaccess' -exec chflags nohidden {} \;`.</sub>

Comment: I know that one, but since I have a lot of .files and .dirs, it makes a mess of my finder.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible. You could maybe symlink the `.htaccess` files to `htaccess` ones that would be always visible.

Comment: That's a shame actually, I will except your answer as it's closest as you could be :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias file of the .htaccess file. Open Terminal app, navigate to the folder than contains the .htaccess file, and enter:

```
mv .htaccess\ alias htaccess
```

This will only create a visible file that links to the .htaccess file for editing and for only that one, not every .htaccess file.